# Efficiently rotate a 2-d numpy array

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I have 2-D numpy array of size about 5000x5000 and I need to rotate it by any given angle theta. I was using scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate(). However the problem is that is that it is too slow. Is there a significantly faster way of doing it?
P.S- Even if the interpolation accuracy low, it wont matter

Comment: Have you tried setting the "order" parameter to 0 and setting the "prefilter" parameter to "False"?

Comment: Yes. But only with a marginal improvement.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do the arrays have to be so big? Could you downsample them and just rotate the downsampled images?

Comment: @littleO Well because they are used for creating astronomical images of extreme precision.If we use a smaller array we lose on accuracy which is not really an option.

Comment: @AnirbanDutta I am dealing with the same problem, did you get any solution?